# where can i find most up to date statistics on programming/scripting languages most used

Tags: programming-languages, statistics

I can't find real, up-to-date information on what programming and scripting languages are most often used today,
and in which environment (e.g. web, desktop or mobile).

Where can I find such info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [TIOBE index](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html).

Comment: TIOBE - The Importance of Being Earnest

Comment: Worth reading this if you're looking at the TIOBE index: http://lambda-diode.com/programming/the-tiobe-index-is-meaningless